# Passing stdout colored output to grunt output

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a grunt custom task that runs mocha tests but I can't figure out how to have grunt take the colored output from mocha and display it as it does when running the mocha command directly. Ie: grunt strips out the colors or does not pass them through. Here's the grunt task:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
grunt.registerTask('mocha', 'Run unit (Mocha) tests.', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    var cmd = "mocha -R Spec tests/mocha/*.js";
    exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (stdout) {
            grunt.verbose.or.write(stdout);
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

I realize there's a grunt-mocha plugin I could use (and have used) but I'm trying to eliminate dependencies and will also be doing some customization on this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135579/node-js-spawn-with-colors/9137636#9137636).

You need to add `--colors` to force Mocha to output ANSI color codes, otherwise it disables colors automatically since it isn't outputting to an actual terminal.

```
var cmd = "mocha --colors -R Spec tests/mocha/*.js";
```

Comment: Found this while looking into how to disable colors. Tried `--no-colors` and it worked. Thanks!