# How do I preserve colors in the console when running a script from a spawned child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, mocha.js, child-process

I have a mocha file full of Selenium tests. When I run mocha from the command line like normal, I get this nice formatted and colorized output thanks to the [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) module.

[image]

This looks great and works wonderfully, but running manually only runs the tests against a single environment. To run the tests in multiple environments in parallel, Sauce Labs (Selenium cloud hosting) recommends spawning mocha child processes. I built this into a Gulp task in our project.

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
  var targets = [
    'windows.chrome',
    'windows.firefox',
    'windows.ie',
    'mac.chrome',
    'mac.firefox',
    'mac.safari',
    'linux.chrome',
    'linux.firefox'
  ];

  function run_mocha(target, done) {
    var env = Object.assign({}, process.env);
    env.TARGET = target;

    var mocha = exec('mocha ./test/test-runner.js', {env: env}, done);
    ['stdout', 'stderr'].forEach((stream) =>
      mocha[stream].on('data', (data) => process[stream].write(`${target}:${data}`))
    );
  }

  var jobs = targets.map(
    (target) => new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => run_mocha(target, resolve)
    )
  );

  return Promise.all(jobs).then(() => {
    console.log('ALL SUCCESSFUL');
  });
});
```

This works great but the output completely loses the colorization. It was also injecting superfluous newlines but I was able to fix that by swapping out `console.log` and `console.error` for `process.stdout.write` and `process.stderr.write`.

[image]

You can see that lines printed from gulp are colorized and work fine, but the minute it spawns the child processes any lines printed from there lose their color. It's not the end of the world but now I'm curious what is going on and how to fix it. I've learned a bit about ANSI escape codes but I'm still very confused about what's going on. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried any of the answers mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135579/node-js-spawn-with-colors

Comment: I did mess around with `spawn` and the `stdio` property as per that question. I was able to supply `inherit` to `stdio` which forced the child process to adopt the same output streams as the parent, which did also enable colors. The issue I ran into was that I wanted to prepend each line with the target environment when the tests are running in parallel so that I know what lines go to which test runs. There was no way to do that from the parent as far as I could tell. I prefer to pipe the child streams so I can transform them in the parent. Dan's answer below solved the color issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found this question:
[Node.js spawn with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135579/node-js-spawn-with-colors)

It looks like it's an issue with Mocha, where it's detecting that its output is not going to be stdout. You'll need to specifically enable colors:

`exec('mocha ./test/test-runner.js --colors')`

Comment: Thank you. This fixed mocha's own output to properly include the colors within the child process. It also put me on the right track to finding out that the [colors](http://npmjs.org/package/colors) module also has a flag to explicitly enable colors except it's singular intead of plural: `--color`. Adding both flags to the spawned mocha process enabled all the colors in both mocha and the Selenium web driver. Thanks again!